# Rails form file upload newbie issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue retrieving my file upload information. I am just starting to learn Rails.

I am using ruby 2.0.0p0
And Rails 4.0.0.beta1

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@person, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :photo %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And in my person.rb model:

```
def photo=(file_data)
logger.debug("PHOTO")
logger.debug(file_data)
logger.debug("END OUTPUT PHOTO")
unless file_data.blank?
  @file_data = file_data
  self.extension = file_data.original_filename.split('.').last.downcase
end
end
```

I can see in my console that nothing happens (no "PHOTO" output), the photo method is never called. 
Why is that?

When I looked in the console I also saw this line that got me worried:

```
Unpermitted parameters: photo
```

What does that mean?

Comment: If you are just starting to learn Rails, I wouldn't be using the Rails 4 beta until it's officially released. The exact problem you're running into likely wouldn't have happened in Rails 3.2.

Comment: You are right. I guess I didn't pay attention when I installed Rails. I will try to switch back to 3 (my learning book is for Rails 3 anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, where you're dealing with `params`, you need to use `.permit` to list the attributes the form is allowed to post:

```
@person = Person.new(params.require(:person).permit(:photo))
```

Alternatively, if you used Rails' scaffolding generator, you might instead have a `person_params` method where you would need to add the `:photo` attribute:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:photo, :name, etc...)
end
```

Comment: Yes, found it. Makes a lot of sense. Thank you.